# Why can't my Facebook friends see the "languages I know"?

Tags: facebook

On Facebook I decided to show off with the **languages** I know.
Now, when I click on my "Profile" I can see "*Knows French, English, German and 4 others*" just under my name.

**Problem**: My friends can NOT see it. *(the point of Facebook is to be seen, right?)*

In **Privacy Settings**, I use "Customize": everything is "Friends only" (except my email address which is "Only me"), which is not very restrictive, so I guess it is not a privacy settings problem.

Any idea what I have to do to make the languages visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They could still be using the old Facebook UI. which is upgradable http://www.facebook.com/about/profile/.

You also need to make sure

> See your likes, activities and other connections

is set to the right privacy level.

You can check the various levels of visibility of your profile.
http://www.facebook.com/[name]?viewas=100000686899395

Comment: I can't find the "See your likes, activities and other connections" setting in "Choose Your Privacy Settings > Customize settings". Is it in another place I didn't think about? My friend is using the new profile, and still can only see where I live, but not the languages.

Comment: @Nicolas It is in `Choose Your Privacy Settings > Connecting on Facebook`

Comment: Great, that works! Awarding you the bounty :-) Thanks a lot for always giving great tips!

Comment: Looks like I have to wait 14 hours before I can give it...

Comment: i have same problem languages i speak is not shown on my profile...i do have alot of things limited but the thing is what should i change? i cant just keep my profile open to all of my friends.

Comment: @helpme see the comments above

Answer (score 0):

Unlike posts/comments/messages, changes to settings on your Facebook profile sometimes take several hours before they are seen by everyone.  Check again the next day.

Comment: It has been 5 days already.

Answer (score -1):

Customize your language settings.You can share it for friends,only me,public or custome.[image]

Comment: I believe the OP says that all settings are set to _Friends only_.